# unable to find the temporary location for signtool. exiting

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, msbuild-4.0

I am try to digitally sign .dll, .exe and .msi files using signUserFiles.exe, I have configured signing steps into Cruise control tool and when I try to build our project (abc.proj file) using cruise control tool then I am getting below error

EXEC (0,0): error: Unable to find the temporary location for signtool. Exiting...

c:\work\UCA7.3_8.1GA\Client\Sign.targets (31,6):

errorMSB3073: The command "C:\Programs\Signing\Windows\signUserFiles.exe -as -fd sha256 -file c:\work\UCA7.3_8.1GA\Client\UCA\bin\Release\53xxPCApp.exe" exited with code 1.

I have written commands as below

while same is working fine if I build abc.proj directly from command prompt window using "msbuild abc.proj" command

Please help me

Regards
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

SignTool docs can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/signtool

On my dev VM, I see signtool.exe in the following locations:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\signtool.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe

I am not familiar with "SignUserFiles.exe" but I always use the Win32 SDK exe and perhaps havent stumbled across that file name. I always run signtool as a CC.Net "executable task". A little more work perhaps, but I prefer granular control of these things.

See https://ccnet.github.io/CruiseControl.NET/projects/ccnet/wiki/Executable_Task.html for details re: the executable task.